# checkbox updating ng-model of another field

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I am trying to use a checkbox to set the date for another input field.  I can't make it work.  Any help would be appreciated.  I have created a [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wqLmncw/) to demonstrate what I am trying to do. As you can see the checkbox does enter the date, but doesn't change the project.dateReturned model.   I am trying to use ng-if, maybe there is a better way. Thanks for helping.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="ctrl">

<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="project.returned" ng-init="checked=true" 
  name="project.returned"></td><br>

<td><span ng-if="project.returned" name="returned" 
   ng-init="project.dateReturn" ng-model="project.dateReturned">{{date |
    date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span></td>


<pre>{{project.returned}}</pre>
<pre>{{project.dateReturned}}</pre>

'use strict';

var ctrl = function ($scope) {
   $scope.date = new Date();

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-model is for two way databinding and only works on editable fields (ie, input tags)

I believe what you want is something like:

```
<input type="text" ng-if="project.returned" name="returned" 
   ng-init="project.dateReturn" ng-model="project.dateReturned" 
   value="{{date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}"</input></td>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply -- i would rather not have to enter the date via an input field.  i would like for it to get set with the checkbox and also update the project.dateReturned model.  I hope that make sense.

Comment: Angular 2 will let you do this in a less convoluted way, but really the best way to do this here is by setting a variable that dateReturned reads from.

Another way you might try is by doing what I've suggested but make the input field hidden and then use the result of that in a one way bind to the span tag using {{project.dateReturned}}

Answer (score 0):

You can use watch() for updating the model like the following.

View:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel">
<input type="text" ng-model="dateReturned"><br/>
{{dateReturned}}
```

Controller:

```
  $scope.$watch("checkboxModel", function(is_cbox_checked){
    if (is_cbox_checked == true){
        $scope.dateReturned = new Date();
    } else {
        $scope.dateReturned = '';
    }
  });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/7ewZhknT656NSK5LTqf1?p=preview

Comment: thanks for the info -  i am noticing that this doesnt seem to work in a ng-repeat.